# Como saber cual es el checkbox que lanzo el evento OnCheckedChanged en asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente.
Muestro informacion de usuarios en una tabla, 
y ademas en la fila de cada usuario hay un checkbox que dice
si el usuario esta bloqueado o no, quiero que cuando el checkbox
de un usuario cambie de estado actualizar su propiedad Disabled en
la base de datos.
La vista seria asi:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ListaDeUsuarios"
                ShowFooter="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="4"
                CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
                ItemType="Proyecto.Models.Usuario" DataKeyNames="Id" 
                SelectMethod="GetUsuarios"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bloqueado">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:CheckBox Checked=<%# Item.Disabled %> runat="server" 
                                        AutoPostBack="True"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"></asp:CheckBox>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Mi duda es que poner en el metodo

```
 public void Check_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }
```

que me permita saber cual es el checkbox que lanzo el evento y
y que usuario representa?

Answer (score 2):

En general el parámetro `sender` corresponde al control que lanzó el evento por lo que en este caso:

```
public void Check_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

    // ...
}
```

`checkbox` contiene al checkbox correcto

Comment: Faltaría obtener la información del Usuario (por ejemplo su Id) para actualizar su estado

Comment: Gracias por responder, de esa forma obteno el checkbox pero como dice Davlio, de que forma podria conocer el usuario al que representa el checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma resolvi:

en la definicio de los checkboxs la adicione una propiedad username

```
<asp:CheckBox Checked=<%# Item.Disabled %> runat="server" 
                                        AutoPostBack="True" username = "<%# Item.UserName %>"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"></asp:CheckBox>
```

y defini el evento asi

```
 public void Check_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (sender != null)
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
            string username = checkbox.Attributes["username"];

            UserManager manager = new UserManager();
            Usuario usuario = manager.FindByName(username);

            usuario.Disabled = checkbox.Checked;
            manager.Update(usuario);
        }
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda.